# How to check if numbers match for if statement vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Will you please give me a gide line on how to solve my current problem. I'm not sure how to put this in practice.

I have a **counter** which increase by **one** in a for statement
I want to add a if statment that needs to do the following:

```
Dim count as decimal = 1
For i As Integer = 1 To 400 - 1
   If count = 3 or count = 6 or count = 9 or count = 12 ..and on and on
       'All the numbers that mathes the count
   Else
       'All the numbers that does not match
   End if

   count += 1
Next
```

I want a simpaler method on how to write the If count = 3 or count = 6 and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the count should be dividable by 3 without a rest (as it seems to be the case), you can use the `Mod` operator: [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

The `Mod` operator will divide 2 numbers and will return the remaining, so e.g `14 Mod 3` will be `2`. So the only check, you need to do, is if `count Mod 3 = 0` like:

```
Dim count as decimal = 1
For i As Integer = 1 To 400 - 1
   If count Mod 3 = 0 then
       'All the numbers that mathes the count
   Else
       'All the numbers that does not match
   End if

   count += 1
Next
```

Comment: I think i fell in love with Mod

Answer (score 2):

1) Why do you have `i` and `count` which appear to always be the same value?

2) Two possible solutions: either the `Mod` operator as others have noted, assuming you actually want every third number, or:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 400 - 1
   Select Case i
       Case 3,6,9,12,15....
           'Do stuff here for matching
       Case Else
           'All the numbers that does not match
   End Select
Next
```

Comment: I never knew one can use the select case like that. Thank you Juffy

Answer (score 1):

Modulus is your friend.

```
number1 Mod number2


if count MOD 3 = 0
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about syntax, but you need to use `Mod` operator:

```
Dim count as decimal = 1
For i As Integer = 1 To 400 - 1
   If (count Mod 3) = 0
       'All the numbers that mathes the count
   Else
       'All the numbers that does not match
   End if

   count += 1
Next
```